# How to install a wood mantel on an existing stone mantel

Tags: wood, installation, stone

I have the option to put a boxed mantel (hollow) or regular mantel on top of this pre-existing stone mantel. What would be the best way to install it?

Could I use glue? If not, what kind of screws, drill and bits I could use? Screw it top to bottom, close to the wall?

[image]

Comment: That's a _very_ small picture and there's some red text on a red background that's really hard to read. A better pic would help. So would a better description of "boxed mantel" vs "regular mantel". How thick is the existing mantel and do you know what kind of stone? How thick is the new mantel? Please [edit] these details and as many others as you can think of into your original post (_don't_ put them down there in the box labeled "Your Answer").

Comment: I would place another mantel directly on the existing with some construction adhesive. For better effect, the addition should be slightly larger on 3 sides.